# Trim Tcl String unexpected behaviour

Tags: string, indexing, tcl, trim

I'm currently experiencing unexpected behaviour using TCL.
I have a string like "alternate [a-z]" and I'm using the following command to get the index of my alternate.

```
set stemp [ string trim $test "alternate \s"]
```

The output is for [b-z] is [b-z] for "alternate a" however I get " ". Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is exactly as documented. The command works by trimming off, from each end, any consecutive sequence of characters that occur somewhere in the second argument. Regardless of what the string in the second argument is, it is just used as a set of characters and never matched, per se, with the leading or trailing substrings of the first argument.

E.g.

```
string trim foobar afro
# -> b
```

It could be `::textutil::trim` that you want: that command trims according to a regular expression.

```
package require textutil

::textutil::trim foooofoooofoo foo
# -> oofoooo
::textutil::trim faouofeoiofyo f.o
# -> uofeoio
```

Documentation: [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [textutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html) package